# Add lines to tabular-inline, after saving... django-admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

first of all want to thank in advance all the help you provide to the global community, it is an invaluable service. I write code as a hobby, and now I want to finish a project (my very first) that I have as a personal goal and will serve to help a nonprofit organization, now I find myself in a somehow awkward position, since English is not my native language, so finding the answer (which is probably already on StackOverflow) is a problem for me. Also this is my first question ever... Hope do it well.
BTW Django it's fantastic... I have these two models:

```
# models.py
class CabMovimiento(InfoComun):

    """
    Guarda información de la cabecera de los movimientos
    internos de equipos, salvo préstamos. Hereda de
    InfoComun los campos.
    """

    nro = models.IntegerField(
        default=lambda: ult_nro_mov('cm'), verbose_name="Número", blank=True)
    det = models.ManyToManyField(
        'inventario.Equipo', through='DetMov', verbose_name="componente")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Movimiento Interno'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Movimientos Internos'

    def los_detalles(self):
        return "\n".join([d.serie for d in self.det.all().filter(self.id)])

    los_detalles.short_description = "Detalles"


class DetMov(models.Model):

    """
    Guarda el detalle de cada documento generado por los
    movimientos internos, a excepción de los préstamos.
    """

    cab = models.ForeignKey('CabMovimiento')
    eqp = models.ForeignKey('inventario.Equipo', verbose_name='Equipo/s')
    tip_mov = models.ForeignKey(
        'inventario.Tmetl',
        limit_choices_to={
            'asociacion': 'E', 'tipo': 'M'
        }, verbose_name='Tipo de Movimiento')
    for_mov = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=fmov,
        default='U', verbose_name='Forma Movimiento')
    diag = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Diagnóstico')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Detalle de Movimiento'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Detalles de Movimientos'
```

I have read and reread the documentation of django (1.5) about signals, save and save_related methods, I have followed several tutorials here and in other no less interesting blogs, but I can not get what I want ....
I need to detect if the for_mov field, which is part of DetMov, changes value, similar to a status field but refers to a way of moving something and may be 'U', for one, or 'C' for complete, that refers to a set of something.

Once detected and if a simple movement('U'), must ignore the change or addition, but in case of a complete movement ('C'), you must search the database and add more rows to the tabular-inline and save it. I know how to do queries, but do not know how to add them ... I think I'll have to use RAW Sql, though less elegant, but not discarded.

Sorry if it's something very simple, and sorry if you do not understand what I want, since I'm using GTranslate. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential solution would be to override your `save()` method on `DetMov` so that you fetched the latest value of it and check if it's changed.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id and self.for_mov == 'C':
        stored_for_mov = DetMov.objects.get(id=self.id).values_list('for_mov', flat=True)[0]
        if stored_for_mov != self.for_mov:
            # The stored value isn't 'C'
            # Add the other records you need to.
    super(DetMov, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm not quite sure if you need to prevent the save in the case of 'U'. I didn't really follow that part, but this should help you solve the problem you're having. You could also pull this all into a `post_save` signal as well.

Comment: No, i don't want to prevent save if 'U', **in that case 'PASS'**, this is what i'm looking for... ** ¡¡¡Muchas Gracias!!!! **